# Replaced 3-way lamp socket and cap doesn't fit

Tags: socket

I bought a replacement 3-way lamp socket and the cap on the new one is too small to thread into the lamp base.  I went to the hardware store and purchased an adapter so it would fit on the new lamp socket cap.  BUT now with the extra height of the adapter my harp is too short.  I found a floor lamp in the house to put on the lamp but now the lamp looks ridiculous as too much of the lamp socket shows and it is much taller than the matching lamp.  Is there a socket I can purchase with a larger socket cap so I don't have to remove the original thread from inside the lamp and can have the right size harp on the lamp?  I have been searching online but do not see offering for a larger cap on the socket.  Any help will be appreciated otherwise I suppose I am going to have to take to a lamp specialty shop.

Comment: A plumbing and electric specialty shop may have what you need. These are getting fewer in number because of the big box home stores, but the guys inside usually know there stuff and are helpful (The few that are left).

Comment: The people at the older hardware stores in town also usually know their stuff, and can find you the correct pieces.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a 3-way socket with a 1/4" base.

[image]

Search for that on the internet and you will find them for sale: [3-way lamp socket with 1/4" threaded base](http://www.ebay.com/itm/3-way-brass-plated-lamp-socket-with-large-hole-1-4-IPS-TR-28-/200606393490)